# Webpack node global modules

Tags: node.js, webpack

How to configure webpack.config.js to global node modules support in browser?

I tried:

```
{
    global : true,
    process: true,
},
```

On build error occured:

> can't find module 'fs'.

```
{
    fs: 'empty',
}
```

I tried call `fs.existsSync(path)` in js file. In browser error occured:

> `fs.existsSync` is not a function.

Comment: Well, the browser doesn't have access to the file system, so a module like `fs` doesn't make sense in the browser. It's unclear to me what your question is.

Comment: By using gulp with browserify it's work

Comment: Browserify uses https://github.com/substack/brfs. All that does is *inline* the file if it can statically determine the path. The way to do this in webpack would be to `require` the file using the `raw` loader: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader .

Answer (score 2):

you should try and set the target for webpack to node, with something like this:

```
module.exports = {
 devtool: "source-map",
 target: "node",
 ...
}
```

This post helped me alot: http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I

> The target: 'node' option tells webpack not to touch any built-in
>   modules like fs or path.