# Error loading in audiosprite - Module not found: 'child_process'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to load in [audiosprite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audiosprite) in my React app which is running on a Webpack server and I'm getting the following error:

> Module not found: 'child_process' in
>   C:\Users\BenLi\Desktop\development
>   projects\app\node_modules\audiosprite

Have no idea what this could be or why it's occurring with this module as apparently, Webpack should not throw `child_process` errors as it comes with it.

I'm including it in my app like so:

```
import audiosprite from 'audiosprite';
```

The error in coming from here in the file:

```
function spawn(name, opt) {
  opts.logger.debug('Spawn', { cmd: [name].concat(opt).join(' ') })
  return require('child_process').spawn(name, opt)
}
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Very tricky question (hard to debug code that you cannot see).  Thanks for putting out the bounty and choosing right answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**

There is **no** way around this unless you (maybe) switch to [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) (need to test this myself) which offers a [`browserify-fs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-fs) module. Since the browser has no access to the file system or child processes anyways, the module `audiosprite` can't be used in this usecase. The browser cannot do what it's incapable of.

**Explanation**

This is because of Webpack. Webpack, by default, is designed to compile code to run in a web-browser environment. The whole reason it exists is to bundle everything up to be browser-friendly (hence the name "web pack").

Node offers some built-in modules such as `child_process`, `path`, `os`, `fs`, etc. **that only exist in a Node environment**. When Webpack comes along and tries to bundle code for the browser, the browser *does not have access to these modules*. Thus, when modules such as `audiosprite` use `child_process`, Webpack bundles them for the web by default and you no longer have access to these modules. This explains why the error reports that the "module is not found".

**"Solutions"**

A "fix" is to specify your Webpack configuration to compile for usage in a Node-like environment, where you *do* have access to these built-in modules. That way, Webpack won't mess with the built-in modules and `child_process` can be used. You can do this by specifying the `target` option. From [the Webpack Configuration documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target):

> #### `target`
>
> - `"web"` Compile for usage in a browser-like environment (default)
> - `"node"` Compile for usage in a node.js-like environment (use `require` to load chunks)
>
> <sup>(documentation cut for brevity)</sup>

But there's a consequence. Because of you setting your target as a Node environment, `require` will not work when using the browser as there is no `require` in the browser environment.

What you can do is keep the target environment the same (`"web"` by default) and try to mock the module for what you need. With the [`node` option](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node):

> ### `node`
>
> Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff:
>
> - `<node buildin>`: `true`, `"mock"`, `"empty"` or `false`

And apply it to the Webpack configuration file:

```
node: {
    fs: "mock"
}
```

But this will error out telling you:

> Error: No browser version for node.js core module 'fs' available

So this is just by design. There is nothing you can do because bundling for the browser environment will inevitably forbid you from accessing the file system because it can't. You can't provide a browser mock for a module which does things that are impossible in the browser. The same goes for `child_process` and others.

**Edit:** I've been looking for some alternatives, and [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) may or may not work. They do offer a [`browserify-fs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-fs) module as a replacement to Node's `fs`. I have yet to test this so I'm not sure if it could be useful but it looks better than what Webpack does now.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. i've added the target: "node" to the end of the webpack config file but it's throwing an error: ReferenceError: require is not defined. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Please bare with me as i'm quite new to all this. I added the exclude line in the webpack config file like this: module:{ loaders: [{   exclude: /node_modules/, }] } but it still throws me the same error... not sure if I did this right or not?

Comment: You can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/yqus3g2z/ where i've added it in along with my other loaders

Comment: Note entirely sure what you mean 'like i did with include'? Also here's the full webpack file if that helps you debug further on your end? https://jsfiddle.net/yqus3g2z/1/

Comment: ok so now it gives me an error within the audiosprite.js saying Module not found: 'fs' in C:\Users\BenLi\Desktop\development projects\music-app\node_modules\audiosprite

Comment: ok so no more errors but let me see if the module works now and will get back to you

Comment: So now the fs function within the soundsprite script does not work now. When I try to run something in the script I get the error fs.existsSync is not a function

Comment: at the top of the audiosprite script there's this line here var fs = require("fs"). so I guess fs is undefined later on in the script because we excluded it correct?

Comment: Ok, what do you suggest I do then? Just to be sure i've followed your instructions right here's a link to the config file as it stands: https://jsfiddle.net/yqus3g2z/2/

Comment: @BenLiger Sorry for not getting back, I'm quite busy. http://stackoverflow.com/q/34015813/5647260 - seems to me that `fs` doesn't work in the browser because browser doesn't have access to the file-system...

Comment: No problem, take your time. Makes sense but I wouldn't have a clue how to give it access to to the file system...

Comment: @BenLiger I don't know what to tell you. Webpack is designed in this way and there's no way around it. Maybe with Browserify and Browserify-fs? Node stuff isn't meant to be run on the browser and you'll get lots of problems.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have to let NPM install the dependency
just

```
npm install --save autiosprite
```

Comment: I think you somehow include it into the browser instead of letting the dependency living in nodejs.
Maybe this issue is somewhat related: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/744

Comment: If I include it in the browser it still has the same issue

Comment: updated my question with where the error is if you know a way of replacing the line with something else