# How to import nools with es6 and webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, nools

I want import [nools](https://github.com/C2FO/nools) in my project with webpack, and I try in 2 steps :

1) install nools with npm :

```
npm install nools --save
```

2) import nools in to the project :

```
import "../node_modules/nools";
```

webpack give me this error :

```
Can not resolve 'fs'
```

and solve this error with add this code to webpack.config.js

```
target:node
```

and webpack build without any error , but when start my  project with npm start ,browser console give me this error :

```
require is not defined
```

my problem is how to import nools with webpack

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42256013/5647260

Comment: If you are building for the browser then you cannot tell webpack that you are building for node.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [nools needs the fs module to read a file from disk](https://github.com/C2FO/nools/blob/4add3fbb5ab8094c1cc729f0df3bf176b5eeffd7/lib/index.js#L24) if a file path (rather than the source string itself) is passed to [`nools.compile()`](https://github.com/C2FO/nools/tree/4add3fbb5ab8094c1cc729f0df3bf176b5eeffd7#noolscompile).

Assuming your browser-based usage of nools in your webpack project never passes a `*.nools` string to `nools.compile()`, then `fs.readFileSync()` is never called, so you can force webpack to resolve `require('fs')` to an empty object by adding this to your webpack config:

```
node: {
  fs: 'empty'
}
```

See webpack's documentation of the `node` options: [1.x](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node) / [2.x](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/)